# node-postgres: Postgres client still connected after client.end()?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a simple connection to my postgres database with node-postgres as shown here:

```
let { Pool, Client } = require("pg");

let postgres = new Client({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  user: "postgres",
  password: "Thisisngo1995!",
});

module.exports = postgres;
```

I test the connection by touching the endpoint with this code:

```
let postgres = require("../../databases/postgres");

exports.postgres_get_controller = (req, resp) => {
  console.log("Reached Here");

  postgres
    .connect()
    .then(() => console.log("connected"))
    .catch((err) => console.error("connection error", err.stack))
    .then(() =>
      postgres.end((err) => {
        console.log("postgres disconnected");
      })
    );
```

I get the desired console.log's signifying that the client was connected, and then disconnected. However, whenever I refresh the page I get this message:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Clients are not reusable. This changes the client to raise errors whenever you try to reconnect a client that's already been used. They're cheap to create: just instantiate a new one (or use the pool)

See this [comment](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1352#issuecomment-312345435) and this [issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/1365)

The solution is to create the pg client for each request.

`ccontroller.js`:

```js
let { Client } = require('pg');

exports.postgres_get_controller = (req, resp) => {
  console.log('Reached Here');
  let postgres = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5430,
    database: 'node-sequelize-examples',
    user: 'testuser',
    password: 'testpass',
  });

  postgres
    .connect()
    .then(() => console.log('connected'))
    .catch((err) => console.error('connection error', err.stack))
    .then(() =>
      postgres.end((err) => {
        console.log('postgres disconnected');
        if (err) {
          console.log('error during disconnection', err.stack);
        }
      }),
    );

  resp.sendStatus(200);
};
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { postgres_get_controller } = require('./controller');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get('/', postgres_get_controller);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server start'));
```

The logs after refreshing the page multiple times to hit the endpoint and executing the controller code:

```
server start
Reached Here
connected
postgres disconnected
Reached Here
connected
postgres disconnected
Reached Here
connected
postgres disconnected
Reached Here
connected
postgres disconnected
Reached Here
connected
postgres disconnected
Reached Here
connected
postgres disconnected
Reached Here
connected
postgres disconnected
```